# Angular how to get scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight using fromEvent

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to get scrollTop, scrollHeight, clientHeight
using fromEvent so I write this simple code

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const obs$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll')
      .pipe(
        map((el) => {
          console.log((el.target as Element).scrollTop);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

but I get undefined what's wrong?

Comment: That first thing that is wrong is you have not told us WHAT is undefined? or when.

Comment: @E.Maggini thanks for the reply (el.target as Element).scrollTop get undefined

Comment: Without having a reproducible example, I'm going to guess that your issue is lifecycle related. Try moving from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit. https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Comment: @E.Maggini stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tdsxfm?file=src%2Fmain.ts  both give me undefined

Comment: Add this to you console.log ` console.log('el init', el);` you will see that it is not the event but that you are targeting something which does not exist on the event returned.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion that document is not an element, that's why the target is undefined.
You can use window or to get the property from an element
for example

```
console.log('window', window.scrollY);
console.log(
        'Element',
        document.getElementById('example').scrollTop
      );
```

demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wuyumv?file=src/main.ts